# Python scraper for steam marketplace only scrapes first page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, steam

I am making a scraper for the steam marketplace. I was able to get it working up until scraping multiple pages where it only scrapes the first page for some reason even when I change the URL.

I tried inputing different url for other pages on the marketplace. The expected result would be that the scraper will scrape the results on said page but the actual result is the marketplace items on the first page.

Here is my code if anyone is interested Thanks!

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import requests

'''
@param inList - input single list
@return value in string of highest price
'''
def highestPriceExtractor(inList):
highestpriceSoup = inList.find(class\_="normal_price")
highestpriceSoup = str(highestpriceSoup)
highestpriceloc1 = highestpriceSoup.find("data-price")
highestpriceloc2 = highestpriceSoup.find("span\>")
highestprice = highestpriceSoup\[highestpriceloc1:highestpriceloc2\]
highestpriceloc21 = highestprice.find("\>") + 1
highestpriceloc22 = highestprice.find("\</")
highestprice2 = highestprice\[highestpriceloc21:highestpriceloc22\]

    highestprice2 = highestprice2.replace("$",'')
    highestprice2 = highestprice2.replace("USD", '')
    return float(highestprice2)

'''
Retrieves the lowest price from a list
'''
def lowestPriceExtractor(inList):
lowestpricearr = \[\]
lowestpriceSoup = inList.find(class\_="sale_price")
for lowestpriceSoup in lowestpriceSoup:
lowestpricearr.append(lowestpriceSoup)
lowestpriceval = "".join(str(x) for x in lowestpricearr)
lowestpriceret = lowestpriceval.replace("$",'')
lowestpriceret = lowestpriceret.replace("USD", '')
return float(lowestpriceret)

def getNextPage(soup, url):
page = soup.find("span", class\_ = "pagebtn")
curpage = url\[str(url).index("#p")+2:len(str(url))\]

    if not page:
        return False
    else:
        nextpage = int(curpage) + 1
        url = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730#p" + str(nextpage)
        return url

def isNextPage(soup):
page = soup.find("span", class\_="pagebtn")
if not page:
return False
else:
return True

'''
list - page to extract from
return- names of each object
'''
def pageNameRetrieve(list):
\# Gets listing in single page and puts in array
\# pricearr: name, lowest price, highest price
listLen = len(list)
nameArr = \[0\] \* listLen
i = 0
for i in range(listLen):
name = list\[i\].get("data-hash-name")
\# extracts lowest price
nameArr\[i\] = name
return nameArr

''''
list - page to extract from
return - price of each object
'''
def pageValueRetrieve(list):
\# Gets listing in single page and puts in array
\# pricearr: name, lowest price, highest price
listLen = len(list)
priceArr = np.zeros((listLen, 2), dtype=float)
i = 0
for i in range(listLen):
lowestprice = lowestPriceExtractor(list\[i\])
\# extracts highest price
highestprice = highestPriceExtractor(list\[i\])
priceArr\[i\]\[0\] = lowestprice
priceArr\[i\]\[1\] = highestprice
return priceArr

def getData (url):
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
return soup

url = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=#p6_popular_desc"

soup = getData(url)

\#list - all listings of page extracted
list = soup.find_all("div", "market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult")
\#Gets amount of listings
listLen = len(list)

\#Gets listing in single page and puts in array
\#pricearr: name, lowets price, highest price

nameArr = pageNameRetrieve(list)
priceArr = pageValueRetrieve(list)

print(nameArr)
print(priceArr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is pulled from api, so you better call these to get you information. Take a closer look into your browsers dev tool network section on xhr tab.

This should point out how you could get your goal, just adapt it to your needs:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


counter = 432800

data = []

while True:
    url = f'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&start={counter}&count=10&search_descriptions=0&sort_column=popular&sort_dir=desc'
    json_data = requests.get(url).json()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(json_data['results_html'])

    for e in soup.select('[id^="resultlink_"]'):
        data.append(list(e.stripped_strings))
    
    if counter < json_data['total_count']:
        counter = counter + 1
    else:
        break
data
```